# React: Is there a way to avoid type errors if a part of a prop isn't available?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing in an array of data as a prop and I'm mapping the content.

*ParentComponent*

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    dataArrays: [0,0,0],
}

<ChildComponent 
   dataArrays = {this.props.dataArrays}
    name = {this.props.name}
/>
```

---

*ChildComponent*

```
this.props.dataArrays.map((block, index) => (
   <div className={index}>
       {block.fullName}
   </div>
```

I'm normally passing in props from the api so it's fine however I am trying to get it to still render properly using the default props if the data isn't coming back for some reason.  The `{block.fullName}` is failing if I don't pass in props since `fullName` is nested within that prop and not directly a prop.  Is there a way to do something like:  `{block.fullName || "Not available"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The logical `&&` operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) is a common way to check that an object exists before trying to evaluate a property on it:

```
// In this case, will evaluate to undefined if block is falsey
this.props.dataArrays.map((block, index) => (
   <div className={index}>
       {block && block.fullName}
   </div>
));
```

Another approach would be to define a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) in your function so that it is guaranteed have some value:

```
// In this case, block will be a default object if the parameter is falsey
this.props.dataArrays.map((block = {fullName: "Not Available"}, index) => (
   <div className={index}>
       {block.fullName}
   </div>
));
```

Yet another way would be to do a [ternary conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
// In this case, if block is falsey it will evaluate to "Not Available"
this.props.dataArrays.map((block, index) => (
   <div className={index}>
       {block ? block.fullName : "Not Available"}
   </div>
));
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer runs through some good options, but why not just clean up your data first?

```
this.props.dataArrays
  .map((block) => (block && block.fullName) ? block : { fullName: 'Not Available' })
  .map((block, index) => (
    <div className={index}>
      {block.fullName}
    </div>
  ))
```

> Is there a way to do something like: {block.fullName || "Not available"}

Alternatively, here's a direct answer to the above: **yes** a syntax for what you want to do *is* [proposed](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) in JavaScript and you can use it now via [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining). It's referred to as the optional chaining operator.

```
this.props.dataArrays
  .map((block, index) => (
    <div className={index}>
      {block?.fullName || 'Not Available'}
    </div>
  ))
```

Be warned though, it's just a proposal and may not make it into the language spec. As I say, I believe the real solution here is just to clean your data of falsey values before you get to the render logic.

Comment: awesome -- I like the proposal.  Hoping it makes it in!